# Confusion about the definition of finite shape category in Jeffrey Strom's book

Tags: category-theory

I was reading about formal definition of diagrams in category theory when I came across the definition of finite shape category:

"Assume $A$ is a small category and $B$ is a category. Then a diagram $C$ in $B$ with shape $A$ is the functor $F:A \to B$. The shape $A$ is finite iff there exists a positive natural number $M$ such that for any composition $f_1 \circ ... \circ f_m$ where $m > M$ there exists $f_i$ such that $f_i$ is the identity morphism."

My question is whether the $f_i$'s are allowed to be repeated? Since if they are then this definition does not hold true for many cases as we can simply let all of $f_i$ be a single non-identity morphism.

Comment: Yes, repetition is allowed, so indeed we can't have any nonidentity *endomorphism* in $A$.

Comment: @Berci So he implicitly rules that out in $A$ by his definition right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The morphisms have to be composable. In order to repeat one of the $f_i$, there would have to be a (non-identity) loop in the category, which I think is the sort of thing we're trying to avoid. There can't be any infinite chains of *distinct* composable morphisms either.

This notion appears to be very similar to the idea of a [direct category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+category).